What are some mistakes that you can make on an iPhone wifi page that can compromise your security
My fingers were shaking when I was trying to turn off my wifi on the wifi setting on my iPhone.
Usually, the only time you get a haptic response on that page is if you click the on/off button. But when I clicked it with my shaky thumb earlier I got a haptic response but nothing seems to have happen, the wifi was still on.
So my question is, what could I have done to trigger a haptic? Did I click the on/off button and quickly turned it back on again with my shaky thumb? But there's no way I didn't see that happen as I tried recreating the scenario.
My main concern is I unknowingly triggered a setting, or joined an untrusted wifi or did something that I didn't want that compromise my device or wifi's security and privacy. Is there anything I can do to ease my mind without reseting my network settings completely?

If shaky fingers is all it takes to self-compromise your own device, then I think you should have bigger problems regarding such device...

@security_paranoid But what could have happened? Why would there be a haptic response if it didn't trigger anything?

Honestly, who knows- it could have even just been a glitch. Or maybe you switched something off then on. Or on then off. The list of possibilities is endless and there's no point speculating: I'm sure you'll be fine.

The first part regarding shaky finger and haptic feedback looks more like a question about Apple products, [apple.se] rather than security. Though, I can't guarantee if the question may be accepted there.

If I tab the WiFi icon several times (as in "with shaky fingers"), I sometimes end up with WiFi still on, sometimes with WiFi off.
Anyway, your iPhone only auto-connects to WiFi network it already knows, so unless the one nearby is compromised I don't see an additional security risk here.
